# How to soak no boil lasagna noodles in water without them sticking to each other?

Tags: pasta, lasagna

I like to soak no boil pasta noodles in water before layering them since it gives them a special taste. However the noodles like to stick to each other in whatever container i put them in. How do you prevent them?

Comment: Do you mean texture or flavor @BarAkiva? I'm not sure how soaking them would change the taste of the end result, could you elaborate for my own curiosity?

Comment: Why not just get regular and soak them in hot water?

Comment: This might be a good use for one of those 'microwave bacon racks'.  I'd also be one to try putting a little bit of rice in between layers so they can't make complete contact, and it could be scraped off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Layer them between wax paper, parchment paper or microwave cling film.

Comment: An edit and an upvote.  **;-)** Microwave cling film is perforated and will allow the water to reach the lasagne whereas normal cling film will prevent the water from reaching them.  *Feel free to roll back:* no offence taken!  **0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby I am in the United States and have never seen or heard of perforated cling film for microwaves. It is not sold in either of the two supermarket chains in our county/area.

Comment: Well.. The only advice I have for you is [not to use any cling film in the microwave](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=cling+film+microwave+cancer&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english_uk) then. **[Here](https://www.lakeland.co.uk/70305/Lakeland-Perforated-Microwave-Cling-Film)** is what I'm talking about. You can [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan)

Comment: @Fabby The OP doesn't mention heating the lasagna noodles (microwave or otherwise), just soaking them.

Comment: @Cindy edited.  (Worthy of an upvote now?)  **;-)**